# Stuck on triangle similarity geometry problem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[The Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8nMw.png)
I'm supposed to solve for x using similarity and can't quite figure out how. I've tried to prove using the angles but haven't had any luck. 
Thanks for any help :D
P.S. if you have a solution that doesn't involve similarity I would still like to see it.

Comment: Is it possible that the little arcs in $A$ and in $F$ mean that those angles are equal? Otherwise the problem is underdetermined.

Comment: I don't think that the arcs mean that the angles have to be equal, because that symbol is used in some of the other problems and the angles aren't necessarily equal.

Comment: Is the answer $x=5$?

Comment: Do the question words mention similar triangles? If they do then I would assume those angles are the same

Comment: @RobertZ  I think the marked angles are equal. Otherwise there is no way of applying similarity. If that is the case, then x = 5 is the correct answer.